# Form Validation in Google Forms based on Spreadsheet values

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a sales team who call leads and sign them up via a form (on our side).  I'd love to use Google Forms for this - there are many advantages (versus the custom CRM we now use).

I need to limit cities to cities we serve, which amounts to about 5000 cities that I have on a spreadsheet.

I tried creating a script to fill in a drop-down menu (similar to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084953/google-spreadsheet-form-populate-form-options-based-on-a-spreadsheet#17520828)), but Google stopped the script with an error stating that it was too many options.  Okay, understandable for a dropdown.  What I really need is a "short text" field that (a) autocompletes, and (b) validates (i.e., doesn't allow answers not on that list).

The upside is that I *can* manipulate the HTML of the form, since I'm going to be putting the form on/into a highly-formatted and branded website.  But I have no idea how to implement this method, either (I know very little HTML/javascript - I'm a python junkie).  It sounds doable to create an autocomplete/validation text field on the page for entry and pass the result onto Google Forms.  No idea how to do that, though.

I've also tried various add-ons for Google Forms and Google Sheets; I think that it's too many values for their limited entry types.

Comment: Probably use a custom web form and then submit the validated data to your Google Form, if you need/want to use a Google Form